# Prove $\frac{\ln x}{x-1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ using derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

$$\frac{\ln x}{x-1} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \qquad x > 0,\ x \neq 1$$

From here we have that

$$0 \leq x-1-\sqrt{x}\ln x$$

So I was trying to prove that $f(x) = x-1-\sqrt{x}\ln x\ \geq\ 0,\ \forall \ x > 0,\ x \neq 1$.

By finding the first derivative we have

$$f'(x) = 1 - \frac{\ln \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

and the second

$$f''(x) = \frac{\ln x}{4x^{3/2}}$$

By analyzing both derivatives we see that in the interval $(0,1),\ f' > 0$. It reaches its minimum at $x = 1$ (not in the domain of the function) and, since $f'' > 0$ for $x > 1$, we have that $f' > 0$ for any value of $x$ in the *domain*, which in turn means that f is an strictly increasing function.

But, how can I show that $f \geq 0$ in the first place?

I haven't been able to do that. I graphed $f(x)$ and get that $f$ is indeed negative for values of $x$ near zero, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Note that the inequality sign changes its direction if you multiply with a negative number. Your first two inequalities are not equivalent for $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: You say that because of $\frac{\ln x}{x-1}$ ? As far as I understand the sign remains the same in the interval $(0,1)$ (numerator and denominator are both negative, so the whole fraction is positive and the inequality remains unchanged).

Comment: No, multiplying with a negative number reverses an inequality.

Comment: @MartinR I think I got what you mean by the sign. For the interval $(0,1)$ I have to show that $f(x) \geq 0$, by showing also that $f' > 0$ for all $x$ there Then for $x > 1$, have to show that $f(x) \leq 0$ (with $f' < 0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$ f(x)=\ln x-\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x}, \text { for }x>0.$$
Then
$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{2x\sqrt x}=-\frac{(\sqrt x-1)^2}{2x\sqrt x}<0, \text{ for }x\neq 1. $$
and hence $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing. So if $0<x<1$, then $f(x)>f(1)=0$ or
$$ \ln x>\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x}.$$
From this one has
$$ \frac{\ln x}{x-1}<\frac{1}{\sqrt x}, \text{ for }0<x<1.$$
On the other hand, if $x>1$, then $f(x)<f(1)=0$ or
$$ \ln x<\frac{x-1}{\sqrt x}.$$
From this one has
$$ \frac{\ln x}{x-1}<\frac{1}{\sqrt x}, \text{ for }x>1.$$

Answer (score 1):

By setting $x=e^t$, it is the same as proving
$$ \forall t\neq 0,\qquad \frac{t}{e^t-1}< e^{-t/2} \tag{1}$$
or:
$$ \forall t>0,\qquad t < 2\sinh\frac{t}{2}. \tag{2} $$
That is trivial since $\sinh$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ ($\sinh''=\sinh > 0$).

Comment: That is a nice proof, but OP is asking about a "Proof ... using derivatives". Shouldn't an answer at least address the flaws in OPs calculation? Otherwise the question  can be closed as a duplicate because it has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @MartinR: $\sinh$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$ since $\sinh'' = \sinh$. Here they appear.